# Почему в 1С вместо добавления пробелов для двух цифр, они суммируются?

Tags: 1с

Есть такой результат кода:

```
Результат.Column = 5;
Результат.Row = 2;
Сообщить(Результат.Column +" "+ Результат.Row);
//Результат 7. Хотелось бы чтобы было так: 5 2
```

Почему в 1С вместо добавления пробелов для двух цифр, они суммируются? Какие есть способы?

Comment: 1С вообще не знаю, но попробуйте так: `"" + Результат.Column +" "+ Результат.Row`, а вообще по-нормальному надо как-то в строки превратить ваши числа. Ну или может в 1С всё же есть какое-то форматирование данных? )

Comment: @CrazyElf, 1С штука страшная - сама приводит к строке, если складывать любой тип данных со строковым.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте лучше явно числа к строке преобразовать перед конкатенацией

```
Сообщить(Строка(Результат.Column) + " " + Строка(Результат.Row));
```

Или так:

```
ТекстСообщения = СтрШаблон("%1  %2", Результат.Column, Результат.Row);
Сообщить(ТекстСообщения);
```